# Continuous Bijection from solid torus to the 3-sphere?

Tags: general-topology

In order to solve a separate problem I was looking at mappings from the solid torus to the 3-sphere. I found what seems to be a continuous bijection, but this seems unlikely and I am trying to figure out where I went wrong (and if it does somehow work, why the inverse is not continuous).

First, I thought about the solid torus as being $T^2_s = \{(e^{i\theta}, re^{i\phi}):\theta,\phi\in\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z, r\in[0,1]\}$. 
It seems like every point in the torus is uniquely identified by some $\theta, \phi,$ and $r$.

Now view $S^3$ as $ \{(z,w)\in \Bbb C^2 : |z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1\} $.

Clearly every $z, w \in \Bbb C$ can be written as $z = r_ze^{i\theta_z}, w=r_we^{i\theta_w}$, but since $|z|^2+|w|^2=1, r_w = \sqrt{(1-r_z^2)}$.

Now if we define $f:T^2_s \to \Bbb C^2$ by $f((e^{i\theta}, re^{i\phi})) = (\sqrt{1-r^2}e^{i\theta}, re^{i\phi})$, we get what seems to me to be a bijective mapping between these spaces. Every element on $S^3$ is of this form, and since $r$ hits every real number between 0 and 1, and $\theta, \phi$ hit every element in $[0, 2\pi)$, the map should be surjective. Further, two elements in $T^2_s$ only map to the same point if all three coordinates are the same (injective). Since this function is composed of continuous functions on the domain being studied, it seems continuous.

Again, this doesn't seem correct to me. Since $S^3$ is not homeomorphic to the solid torus, I know that even if this does hold, the inverse function cannot also be continuous (although I have trouble seeing why it wouldn't be here). Can anyone find an error in my reasoning, or find some set of points where either the function or its inverse is discontinuous? Thanks.

Comment: A continuous bijection between two compact Hausdorff spaces must be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is not uniquely defined when $r=0$ in $re^{i\phi}$. Or stated differently, the argument of a complex number is not uniquely defined for zero.

Answer (score 0):

just in case: taking $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1,$ one solid torus is given by $|z|^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}.$  Another solid torus is given by by $|w|^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}.$

The place they meet is an actual surface, $ |z|^2 =|w|^2 =  \frac{1}{2}.$ This is usually called the Clifford Torus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus